# Arduino in-built LED is not turning off

Tags: arduino-uno

I have an Arduino Uno whose LED, which is connected to  pin 13, is not turning off and it always stays on, and it annoys me.

[image: Arduino UNO]

Touching any exposed pins turns off the LED after removing my hands from the pins it turns back on *slowly*.

However it works perfectly with the programs. This program does turn the LED off and it stays that way while the program is running.

```
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);         
}
```

When I upload other programs that don't use pin 13 then it stays on again. How can I fix this?

Comment: did you set the mode of the pin 13 to output (`pinMode(13, OUTPUT);`) in your `setup` function?

Comment: When i want to use `pin 13` only then i set it as `output` else its not even defined any where in the code

Comment: See: [Uno pin 13 LED mysteriously always ON at 0.14V unless pinMode OUTPUT](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17675/uno-pin-13-led-mysteriously-always-on-at-0-14v-unless-pinmode-output)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't tell it to turn off, it behaves "as it wants". If you don't write a 0 on its pin, how can you force it to stay shut down?

If you want it to be in an off state, force it: in your setup function write

```
pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(13, LOW);
```

No need to refresh it every loop, just in the setup.

Comment: Yeah i know. that was the example i am giving to tell it behaves that way when the pin is not defined/set. Means i have not set `pinMode(13,OUTUPT/INPUT);` and still it stays on.. but when i do define it with `pinmode` than it works the way it supposed to work

Comment: Yes, that's because if you want the board to do (or not to do) something you have to explicitely say it. Otherwise you will have a behavior that can change between runs

Comment: i have another arduio uno who doesn't behave like this one.. its led stays off.

Comment: Again, " you have to explicitely say it. Otherwise you will have a behavior that can change between runs". If you don't tell it to pull it down, it will be in a floating state. Floating means that no one knows what state it will have. So pull it down. Or solder a resistor (any value above 10k are fine) between the 13 pad and ground. Or place a resistor of the same value in the header between pin 13 and ground. But you have to set a value

Answer (score 0):

You could try to actually remove the LED with a soldering pen... I haven't tried it however, so you could end up disabling pin 13 (or worst).

Comment: That's my last option..

Comment: As I referred to in my comment on the question ( http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17675/uno-pin-13-led-mysteriously-always-on-at-0-14v-unless-pinmode-output ) this behaviour is normal because of the op-amp they use to drive the LED. The output state is undefined if the pin is configured as an input, and the op-amp may or may not turn on the LED. To be sure, configure the pin as an output. Soldering a resistor or removing the LED seems an overkill. Define the pin as an output if it is not used for anything else, and write LOW to it.

Comment: @AkashKumar you could just put a small square of electrical tape over it, which is also temporary. Don't overthink it!